# Conditionally updating a formula using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to use a VBA Function to insert a formulas into cells based on two conditions.

The conditions are (1) there has to be something in the Description (Column D on my spreadsheet) and (2) the cell I'm pasting the code into has to be blank.

The best way I can see of doing this is with a loop, but I can't figure out how to update the references in my formulas to take account of the new position.

The code below works, but it does not check to see if the cells are empty first.

```
Range("B8").Formula = "=IF(D8="""","""",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Trim(D8),Sheet3!$B$8:$M$7500,2,FALSE)),"""",VLOOKUP(Trim(D8),Sheet3!$B$8:$M$7500,2,FALSE)))"
Range("B8").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("B8:B" & Total), Type:=x1filldefault
'Adds the above formula into the range B8 to B(the last cell in use)
Range("C8").Formula = "=IF(D8="""","""",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Trim(D8),Sheet3!$B$8:$M$7500,3,FALSE)),"""",VLOOKUP(Trim(D8),Sheet3!$B$8:$M$7500,3,FALSE)))"
Range("C8").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("C8:C" & Total), Type:=x1filldefault
'Adds the above formula into the range C8 to C(the last cell in use)
Range("E8").Formula = "=IF(D8="""","""",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Trim(D8),Sheet3!$B$8:$M$7500,4,FALSE)),"""",VLOOKUP(Trim(D8),Sheet3!$B$8:$M$7500,4,FALSE)))"
Range("E8").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E8:E" & Total), Type:=x1filldefault
'Adds the above formula into the range E8 to E(the last cell in use)
Range("J8").Formula = "=IF(D8="""","""",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Trim(D8),Sheet3!$B$8:$M$7500,9,FALSE)),"""",VLOOKUP(Trim(D8),Sheet3!$B$8:$M$7500,9,FALSE)))"
Range("J8").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("J8:J" & Total), Type:=x1filldefault
'Adds the above formula into the range J8 to J(the last cell in use)
Range("A8").Formula = "=If(B8="""","""",Row(A8))"
Range("A8").Select
```

Comment: So you have many rows, and want to loop through all rows and insert a formula in a cell if that row, column D is not empty, and the cell itself isn't empty? How many columns are you looping through?  Is it literally the same formula most of the time? Can you perhaps show some sample data, and sample expected output/how you want it to look/work?

Comment: All your what should be `xlFillDefault` are  `x1filldefault` (with a "one" not an "el")

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but this should do what you want.

In a loop:

```
For i = 8 to Total
    If cells(i, 4) <> "" Then
        AddFormulaIfNotBlank cells(i, 2), _            
        "=IF(D<r>="""","""",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Trim(D<r>),Sheet3!$B$8:$M$7500,2,FALSE))" _
        & ","""",VLOOKUP(Trim(D<r>),Sheet3!$B$8:$M$7500,2,FALSE)))"

        'add rest of formulas here....

    Next i
Next i
```

Helper Sub: populate only empty cells, and adjust the formula for the current row

```
Sub AddFormulaIfNotBlank(c As Range, f As String)
    If Len(c.value)=0 Then
        c.formula = Replace(f, "<r>", c.Row)
    End If
End sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tested this briefly.  it assumes that the currently selected cell is at the top of the column you want to work down through before you start the procedure.  Also there isn't any error handling

```
Sub CopyFormulas()

Dim xlRange As Range
Dim xlCell As Range
Dim xlAddress As String


    xlAddress = ActiveCell.Address & ":$" & Mid(ActiveCell.Address, 2, InStr(1, ActiveCell.Address, "$")) & Mid(Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address, InStrRev(Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address, "$"), Len(Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Address))
    Set xlRange = Range(ActiveCell, xlAddress)
    For Each xlCell In xlRange
        xlAddress = "D" & Mid(xlCell.Address, InStrRev(xlCell.Address, "$"), Len(xlCell.Address))
        If xlCell.Value = "" And Range(xlAddress).Value <> "" Then
            xlCell.Value = "=IF(D8="""","""",IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(Trim(D8),Sheet3!$B$8:$M$7500,2,FALSE)),"""",VLOOKUP(Trim(D8),Sheet3!$B$8:$M$7500,2,FALSE)))"
        End If
    Next xlCell
End Sub
```